# How to install wine on Slackware 14.0 using slackpkg

Tags: software-installation, slackware

I am trying to install wine, using slackpkg, but it can't find it:

```
# slackpkg search wine

Looking for wine in package list. Please wait... DONE

No package name matches the pattern.
```

I can install from SlackBuild, but I would like to use precompiled binaries to save time. Does anybody have experience installing wine in Slack, using slackpkg. I updated the mirrors, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Eric Hameleer's build from http://www.slackware.com/~alien/slackbuilds/wine . Might not be up to date (i.e. build for 14.0 might not be there), but you can try installing it anyway or just rebuild it yourself - on a reasonable machine it should be ready in tens of minutes top.